# How to host MQTTNet websockets broker in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mqtt

I need to host an MQTTNet websocket server in an ASP.Net MVC application. The documentation(https://github.com/chkr1011/MQTTnet/wiki/Server) and the project's github page suggests it to be working only for ASP.Net Core. How do I do that in MVC 5? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is the new version use an older version that had the ability to be hosted in any process. But there was a problem led to this new version. When you host a normal website in IIS, web server may close the process and hence disconnect your MQTT connections. Therefore you can do this only if you know what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Can you please tell me which version of the nuget worked well before? Maybe I can test if it works fine. I would be hosting this on Azure App service. App service wont expose any other ports apart from 80 & 443 due to its sandbox environment. Hence I am trying to use Websockets as a medium for the MQTT broker.

Comment: Prior to version 3 will be fine. But consider this that the pattern of creating both client and server has changed dramatically with the introduction of netcore version. Previous version doesn't have the fluent API and is rather different. But I think you can use any port you like with that.